# Template function link error, C++

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, linker, linkage

Consider the code below:

`header.h`:

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
void f(T const& val);
```

`header.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"
template<class T>
void f(T const& val)
{

}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
    f(5);
}
```

The compiler output is a link error which states:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl f<int>(int const &)" (??$f@H@@YAXABH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I know that if I place the body of template function in `header.h`, my problem will be solved. But why? Why linker can find the body of non template functions but cannot find the body of template functions?